# JWT: correct way to verify AUD claim

Tags: jwt, openid, specifications, verify, audience

I'm in context of managing an openId jws, and I'm not sure about how to verify the `aud` claim.

In details, suppose that I've an application id `myapp.site.com` and I receive an `aud` which value is `myapp.site.com|*|ANY`. I've not found specifications about this format, but reading the `aud` specification into https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken I've supposed to `explode` the string `myapp.site.com|*|ANY` using the "pipe" as separator, and then verify if this array contains the aspected client id (ie `myapp.site.com`).

My question is: whatabout the `*` and `ANY`? there's some specifications about this format? where can I retrieve informations?

Thanks in advance,

Sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a custom thing that is not a standard that I have seen anywhere else, so I guess its up to you to parse it as it is. At the same time the purpose of the audience is for the receiver of a token to be sure the token is aimed for it and not someone else. So its a security risk to accept any token even if the signature is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand the goal of this claim infact my only doubt was about it's value, but I accept "that looks like a custom thing [...]" so thank you again.